# Azure Notification Hub: Sending Messages to Non Registered Devices

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I am using Notification Hub (inbox messages) and during my testing notice that even if we send the message to a tag which is not registered with Hub we get successful response from hub where as I was looking for an error response.

Is there a way to enforce tag validation while sending messages.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a message to the tag which is not registered, then Notification Hub just defined zero targets and makes zero calls to PNS which is not treated as error.

Moreover, initially message goes to the internal system queue and NH immediately returns successful response to the client. So on that moment of time it is not known if any targets exist or not.

There is a feature called Test Send or Debug Send which forces NH to finish processing and return extended outcome to the client. But that feature is designed for debug/troubleshooting purposes only and NH throttles test sends severe.

So, short answer for your question is no.